# How to use LocalStorage on last HTML select value

Tags: javascript, html

How can I set/retrieve the last selected value of a select drop-down with JavaScript? I'm trying to create an onchange function on a select drop-down that that sets the selected option, and then on each page-load, that valued is loaded.

Here is the HTML

```
<select class="testSelect">
    <option value="test1">test1</option>
    <option value="test2">test2</option>
    <option value="test2">test3</option>
    <option value="test2">test4</option>
</select>
```

I'm having a little trouble with the JavaSCript though.

```
var select = document.querySelector(".testSelect");
var selectOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
var getLast = localStorage.getItem(select, lastSelected);
selectOption = getLast;


select.onchange = function () {
   var lastSelected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
   localStorage.setItem(select, lastSelected);
 }
```

and here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5yJNL/1/

Comment: the first parameter of set & getItem should be a string i.e. `'select'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values in your HTML were wrong

```
<select class="testSelect">
    <option value="test1">test1</option>
    <option value="test2">test2</option>
    <option value="test3">test3</option>
    <option value="test4">test4</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
var select = document.querySelector(".testSelect");
var selectOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
var lastSelected = localStorage.getItem('select');

if(lastSelected) {
    select.value = lastSelected; 
}

select.onchange = function () {
   lastSelected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
   console.log(lastSelected);
   localStorage.setItem('select', lastSelected);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2MPPz/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two problems in your code.

1. The first one is an scope problem: The `lastSelected` variable is
   local defined in your function. You must define as global variable.
2. The second one is that the first parameter of `setItem` & `getItem`
       methods should be a `String`

So your **corrected code** looks like:

```
var lastSelected;

var select = document.querySelector(".testSelect");
var selectOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
var getLast = localStorage.getItem('select', lastSelected);
selectOption = getLast;


select.onchange = function () {
   lastSelected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
   localStorage.setItem('select', lastSelected);
 };
```