# How to implement local storage on html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, local-storage

(Updated)Here is the View Source.

For Example: You have a list of Names..I have to use a foreach loop because are over 100 names.  And once the user selects the name, I have there phone number appears once you click on the button.  I need the selected name to stay selected.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html> <!--Required in every html-->
<html>
<head>
    <!--Force browser to use latest version-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <!-- link allows use of .css and script allows use of javaScript -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
    <script src="init.js"></script>-->
<script>
function doFirst(){

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<button id='button'>Click me!</button>-->
    <!--  -->
<h1>    Friday 11-04-2016<br></h1>


    <form action='index.php' method='post'>
        Afternoon Shift Supervisor:
  <select name="name"> <!-- COMBO Box PLUS onchange="submit();return false; makes data appear on selection, refreshs page"-->
                                <!-- AMOUNT(PROID), THEN FILL WITH THE CONTENT(PRONAME)-->
                <option value="Declicious Apples!">Declicious Apples!</option>

                                <!-- AMOUNT(PROID), THEN FILL WITH THE CONTENT(PRONAME)-->
                <option value="Comfy">Comfy</option>

                                <!-- AMOUNT(PROID), THEN FILL WITH THE CONTENT(PRONAME)-->
                <option value="GREEN">GREEN</option>


        </select>
  <script>
var select = document.querySelector("name")[0];
var SelectOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
var lastSelected = localStorage.getItem('select');

if(lastSelected){
  select.value = lastSelected;
}/*
select.onchange = function (){
  lastSelected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(lastSelected);
  localStorage.setItem('select',lastSelected);
}
function updateSelection(which) {
  if (typeof localStorage != "undefined")
    localStorage.setItem("select", which.value);
}
window.onload = function () {
  if (typeof localStorage != "undefined")
    document.querySelector("#sel").value = localStorage["select"];
};*/
</script>

                    phone # :  Comfy
    <br>    On Call Supervisor:
        <select name="name2"> <!-- COMBO Box -->
                                <!-- AMOUNT(PROID IS VALUE..ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY), THEN FILL WITH THE CONTENT(PRONAME)-->
                <option value="Declicious Apples!">Apples</option>  <!-- ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY PRODDESC WILL BE OUTPUT-->
                                <!-- AMOUNT(PROID IS VALUE..ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY), THEN FILL WITH THE CONTENT(PRONAME)-->
                <option value="Comfy">Jeans</option>    <!-- ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY PRODDESC WILL BE OUTPUT-->
                                <!-- AMOUNT(PROID IS VALUE..ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY), THEN FILL WITH THE CONTENT(PRONAME)-->
                <option value="GREEN">VEGGIES</option>  <!-- ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY PRODDESC WILL BE OUTPUT-->
                        </select>

              <!--  TESTING TO VERIFY I GET VALUE OF WHAT WAS SELECTED WORKS!  -->
   Phone #: Declicious Apples! <br><input type='submit' id='click me' value='Submit'><br/>
```

I have also tried(neither are saving the selected value when the page refreshes):

```
  <script>
var select = document.querySelector("name");
var SelectOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
var lastSelected = localStorage.getItem('select');

if(lastSelected){
  select.value = lastSelected;
}
select.onchange = function (){
  lastSelected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(lastSelected);
 localStorage.setItem('select',lastSelected);
}
</script>
<form action='index.php' method='post'>
        Afternoon Shift Supervisor:
  <select name="name">              
<?php foreach($data as $i=>$rows): ?>

<option value="<?=$rows['PRODDESC']?>"><?=$rows['PRODDESC']?></option>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </select>
        <?php $name = $_POST["name"];?>
        phone # :  <?php echo $name; ?>
 <br><input type='submit' name='click me' value='Submit'><br/>
 </form>
```

Comment: That would require cookies, local storage, or storing the selected value on the server.

Comment: @adeneo  thanks I believe that will help, but now that I tried to implement it, but still not changing.  Should I make a new question?

Comment: @Nameishi You understood, server side code won't work, and you said you tried to implement. In this same question, add that as an update, by [edit]ing your question and adding the contents at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it in the server side, use the client side to make it possible.

```js
function updateSelection(which) {
  if (typeof localStorage != "undefined")
    localStorage.setItem("select", which.value);
}
window.onload = function () {
  if (typeof localStorage != "undefined")
    document.querySelector("#sel").value = localStorage["select"];
};
```

```html
<select id="sel" onchange="updateSelection(this);">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

If the Stack Snippets are sandboxed, see the live preview at [**JSBin**](http://output.jsbin.com/peciyetiha).

Comment: Still doesn't save  for me, I added your script and made changes to my HTML below: <select name="name" onchange="updateSelection(this);">    <?php foreach($data as $i=>$rows): ?>
          <option value="<?=$rows['PRODDESC']?>"><?=$rows['PRODDESC']?></option>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

   </select>

Comment: @Nameishi Add the updated code in your question. Can't understand what you have written.

Comment: @Nameishi What you have done is right. Only thing is, please put the script block below the select element, may be, at the end of the page.

Comment: I just put the script under the </select>  and still doesn't help.

Comment: @Nameishi Can you open the console (`F12`) and tell me what's displayed there? Like errors or something. Open the console [**this way**](http://wickedlysmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/win-chrome-2-1.png).

Comment: @Nameishi `var select = document.querySelector("name");` doesn't work!

Comment: var select = document.querySelector(".name"); does not work either. here is my source  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905358/how-to-use-localstorage-on-last-html-select-value

Comment: @Nameishi Use `var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0]`?

Comment: No it has no affect, but I noticed, shouldn't I connect the button name to the script? and on button click save the values that way?  If so..How would I save each value in an option tag in my case..since I am using a for each loop?

Comment: @Nameishi It's totally confusing what you have done. Can we stick with the HTML on the client side alone? Just get rid of all the other code, while keep only the code that is relevant to the `<select>` and `JavaScript` associated with it? Make a snippet with just HTML in JSBin, and let's see if we can solve it?

Comment: I need PHP, im reading from a database. All of my values inside my option tag are being pulled from the database using php.  They do it here so I know it is possible http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: @Nameishi Screw up W3Schools man. Just copy the contents of view source in your browser and try to execute the client side. There's literally no problem with the server side.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean, by copy the contents of view source?  are you saying copy w3Schools? because they are hardcoding the values into the list then taking that value from the list to use as a query.  I need to populate the names of my list from the database because the names change often.

Comment: @Nameishi Mate, screw up W3S. Don't talk about that website. What I am asking is, copy your code's PHP output (which is the `<option>`) tags and then paste it here along with JavaScript, making it HTML & JS, not with PHP. Got it?

Comment: when I do $name = $_POST["name"];   I store my php output into $name.  is that what your asking?

Comment: Sorry I know your trying to help, but I do not know what you mean

Comment: Okay, run the PHP code, on your browser, go to view source, get the source generated, and paste it in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) and send me the link.

Comment: Ohhhhh..im sorry okay I have the view source, but Im un able to access JSBin, so can I edit the question again?

Comment: @Nameishi Okay.