# How to use localStorage in HTML

Tags: javascript

Sorry, I'm new to HTML and after hours I could make my function. But every time I refresh the page, the number is going back to 0. Can anyone add localStorage to my function below (Sorry if I said something that doesn't make sense, I'm new)

```
function answer() {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "<xmp></h4></xmp>";
    }
function add() {
    var num = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;
    if(num == '') num = 0;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = parseInt(num ,10) + 500;
    }

function sub() {
    var num = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;
    if(num == '') num = 0;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = parseInt(num ,10) - 500;
    }
```

Comment: This is not quite a duplicate, but [this question gives hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905358/how-to-use-localstorage-on-last-html-select-value).

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage , and use set and get method

Comment: You've spent quite a few hours choosing a good username for you!