# php dropdown show selected but one value by defaut

Tags: php, sql-server, html, drop-down-menu

i'm using php for stored procedure on sql server. My problems is that i would like to show one value by defaut on the dropdown, but when someone select something else and the page refresh, it must show the what that person choose, not the default one. Here what i had done until now :

```
<form method="post">
            <label for="from"><b>De:</b></label>
            <input  data-date-format='yy-mm-dd' type="text" id="from" name="from" size="6" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['from'])){ echo $_POST['from']; } ?>";/>
            <label for="to"><b>A:</b></label> 
            <input data-date-format='yyyy-mm-dd' type="text" id="to" name="to" size="6" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['to'])){ echo $_POST['to']; } ?>";/>
            <label for="group"><b>Groupe:</b></label> 
            <select type= "text" name="group" id="group" value="";>
            <option><?php if(isset($_POST['group'])){ echo $_POST['group']; } ?></option>
<?php
$sql = " Get_List_ReportStation";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );}
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{ 
?>          
<option selected value="RAL"><?php echo ($row['F1000'] . " " . $row['F1018']); ?></option>       
<?php   
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Valider" name="submit">
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$from = $_POST["from"];
$to = $_POST["to"];
$group = $_POST["group"];
}
?>
```

Any ideas to help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select class="group">
    <option value="test1">test1</option>
    <option value="test2">test2</option>
    <option value="test3">test3</option>
    <option value="test4">test4</option>
</select>
```

Add Javascript to store the users last value into localstorage.

```
var select = document.querySelector(".group");
var selectOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
var lastSelected = localStorage.getItem('select');

if(lastSelected) {
    select.value = lastSelected; 
}

// sets up a onselected
select.onchange = function () {
   lastSelected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
   console.log(lastSelected);
   localStorage.setItem('select', lastSelected);
}
```

Source: [How to use LocalStorage on last HTML select value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905358/how-to-use-localstorage-on-last-html-select-value)

**For your given code try this**

```
<form method="post">
            <label for="from"><b>De:</b></label>
            <input  data-date-format='yy-mm-dd' type="text" id="from" name="from" size="6" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['from'])){ echo $_POST['from']; } ?>";/>
            <label for="to"><b>A:</b></label> 
            <input data-date-format='yyyy-mm-dd' type="text" id="to" name="to" size="6" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['to'])){ echo $_POST['to']; } ?>";/>
            <label for="group"><b>Groupe:</b></label> 
            <select type= "text" name="group" id="group">
            <option><?php if(isset($_POST['group'])){ echo $_POST['group']; } ?></option>
<?php
$sql = " Get_List_ReportStation";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );}
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{ 
?>          
<option value="<?php echo ($row['F1000']."_".$row['F1018']); ?>"><?php echo ($row['F1000'] . " " . $row['F1018']); ?></option>       
<?php   
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Valider" name="submit">
</form>
<script>
var select = document.querySelector(".group");
var selectOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
var lastSelected = localStorage.getItem('select');

if(lastSelected) {
    select.value = lastSelected; 
} else {
    select.value = 'RAL'; // new code
}

// sets up a onselected
select.onchange = function () {
   lastSelected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
   console.log(lastSelected);
   localStorage.setItem('select', lastSelected);
}
</script>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$from = $_POST["from"];
$to = $_POST["to"];
$group = $_POST["group"];
}
?>
```

Comment: yes, i understand, but my information come from my stored procedure, so i don't know what will be in the dropdown.

Comment: Your javascript will run after the information has been populated to your html by php via your stored procedures. Once the html is generated, your client will recieve the html + js and will run the js. This code is independent of the values in your dropdown :)

Comment: Sorrry, i'm beginner. I'm not too much sure. If i get the information from my stored procedure with : ?php echo ($row['F1000'] . " " . $row['F1018']); ? and have _selected value "RAL"_ in my option. RAL is default value, but if someone else take something else, then i called with : php if(isset($_POST['group'])){ echo $_POST['group']; Where exactly i must change to do what you said and keep the same result? thank you again!

Comment: i updated my answer maybe this will solve. I hope. if not, let me know and ill update this further for you.

Comment: it work to show me what i'd select even after reload page, but my default value (RAL) isn't there anymore when i open my page the first time. You know what i means?

Comment: I added a // new code on this one where it sets RAL. You may need to clear your localstorage from your browser in your history settings. or delete the value from your localstorage via the developer console to verify this.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. The trouble is only at open page where there is still nothing selected. I cleared my localstorage and history too.